# How to give a link to each row in bootstrap-vue table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2

I have an `bootstrap-vue` table in my project.
I want to give each row a link (*something like code below*)

```
<template #row>
 <div @click="goToPage">
    {{ item.name}}
 </div>
</template>
```

but do not know how to access table tr in bootstrap
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-parm-ub1lhz?file=/src/App.vue)

i would really appreaciate if someone can help me with it

Answer (score 1):

You can add `selectable` to your table and event `row-selected`:

```
<b-table select-mode="single" ref="selectableTable" selectable @row-selected="onRowSelected" small :fields="fields" :items="items" responsive="sm">
```

and then create method:

```
methods: {
  onRowSelected(item) {
    console.log(item)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [@row-clicked](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table#comp-ref-b-table-events) event, which as the name suggests is triggered when a row is clicked.

The method is sent the `item` for the row which was clicked, so you can access any information from the item if needed. Along with the `index` and native click `event`.

```js
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { age: 40, first_name: 'Dickerson', last_name: 'Macdonald' },
      { age: 11, first_name: 'Larsen', last_name: 'Shaw' },
      { age: 89, first_name: 'Geneva', last_name: 'Wilson' },
      { age: 38, first_name: 'Jami', last_name: 'Carney' }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    onRowClicked(item, index, event) {
      console.log(item)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.12/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="p-3">
  <b-table striped hover :items="items" @row-clicked="onRowClicked"></b-table>
</div>
```